# Call Kinesis Firehose vs Kinesis Stream directly from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis

I have a need where I wanted to push some data to S3 from lambda. The data coming to Lambda is from a Dynamodb streams. Since, for pushing to S3 bucket, use of Firehose is considered best as it batches and buffers the data before pushing to S3 as well as provide the retry strategy. So, I am using Firehose instead of directly pushing to S3.

But I observe lot of people push data from Lambda to Kinesis Stream from which data is pushed to Kinesis Firehose instead of directly pushing to Firehose from AWS Lambda. Is there any reason of doing it this way? Any benefits? What are the drawbacks of pushing to Kinesis firehose directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose** meets your needs, then definitely use it! It takes care of most of the work for you, compared to normal Kinesis Streams.

The only time you would ***not* use Firehose** is when you have a different destination (eg you want to process the data on Amazon EC2 instances) or you want more control of the streams and shards (eg to process certain producers on specific shards to retain ordering on a per-shard basis).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually my question is regarding using Kinesis Firehose directly from lambda or through Kinesis Streams? What's the difference in that?

Comment: Firehose is basically a "simpler" Kinesis, with limited output options. If you can use one of the Firehouse output options (in your case, Amazon S3), then it makes much more sense to use Firehose than Streams. It works "out of the box" rather than having to write your own consumer.

Comment: So, basically call Firehose directly from lambda, right? And not call Streams which further passes the data to Firehose and then to S3, right?

Comment: Correct. Just call [`put_record()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.put_record)

Comment: Firehose doesn't offer the flexible scaling that Kinesis Streams does: if the default ingress does not meet your needs then you need to submit a support ticket. There's also a note in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html) that over-provisioning can result in small batches, which seems strange but could be a problem.

Comment: Plus, Kinesis Streams lets you add multiple consumers to the stream.